# The use of the word "hear" in context

Tags: word-usage

Tell me please if the following use of *hear* is appropriate in the sentence.

> Rob is telling the funniest joke, you should **hear** it.

Would it be more correct to use *listen* instead. Although I am not a native English speaker, *listen* doesn't sound good to me in the context.

Comment: We **hear** jokes. Have you **heard** this joke before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1: *Rob is telling the funniest joke, you should **hear** it*

...is actually quite natural, but so is...

> 2: *Rob is telling the funniest joke, you should **listen** [to it]*

The difference between ***hear*** and ***listen*** is similar to that between ***see*** and ***look***. In both cases, the second verb implies a deliberate act that involves *paying attention* - hence #2 above more strongly implies *stop talking yourself and/or listening to someone else, and **pay attention** to the joke Rob is telling right now.*

But if we shift to the *past* tense...

> 3: *Rob **told** the funniest joke, you should **hear** it*

is also perfectly natural *(**Listen to me now**, while I tell you the joke I heard from Rob).* But...

> 4: *Rob **told** the funniest joke, you should **listen** [to it]*

...is at least *slightly* unusual. Maybe the speaker means the same thing as in #3 above, maybe he means you should go and ask Rob to tell the joke again, or maybe he means just find *anyone* who heard the joke and get them to repeat it.

---

Note that the word ***it*** is syntactically required with ***hear*** above, but ***to it*** isn't required with ***listen*** in #2, where the intended sense is ***listen right now*** (to the joke that Rob is currently telling). Nor is it required in #4, if we're in the relatively unusual situation that the joke is ***about to be retold***.